# Sign up to Telegram without installing native mobile app

Tags: telegram-messenger

Is there a way to sign up to Telegram with the web version and a phone number just by receiving an SMS, without the need to install a native mobile app?

Comment: It is about computer software within the scope defined in the help centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can run telegram without using one of the apps.

You can run the app on a virtual android device running on your computer if you wish to not use the app on a real phone, but you will probably want to keep the virtual device available, to make sure you can login on new devices.

You will need to verify a number, but this can be done with any number that can accept SMSs, or even some landlines.

Comment: I only want to run it on my laptop and log in to it from there. I don't have any other devices that are ever online. Are you saying that can be done without a smartphone being involved at any point? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
No need to any apps so far on any platform. Just a working mobile number capable of receiving SMS is enough. But telegram works better experienced using one of the apps.

Comment: If you can sign in without an app, explain how.

Comment: Am I right that "app" means "terminal program run on a smartphone or smartphone emulator"?

Comment: think of a browser and web version of telegram